# SolrIndexSearch not returning any results for Numeric Range Query

Tags: solr, lucene

I have following code which is working for andy Term queries with String fields but not working for Numeric fields.  It does not return anything for int, tint, long, tlong fields!  Shouldn't it work same as string?

```
myClass  extends SearchHandler {

@Override
public void handleRequestBody(SolrQueryRequest req, SolrQueryResponse rsp) {

SolrIndexSearcher search = req.getSearcher();


SolrIndexSearcher.QueryCommand cmd = new QueryCommand();
SolrIndexSearcher.QueryResult result = new QueryResult();

cmd.setQuery(q);
cmd.setOffset(0);
cmd.setLen(10)

result = search.search(result, cmd);
```

Comment: where local variable q was set?